# Find previously edited system files

Tags: upgrade, system

I am upgrading a fairly old server and *I wish to find all of the system config files that I **may** have previously edited* e.g. samba (smb.conf), NFS (exports), networking etc. Bash history can't help with this particular server. I know I've edited some, but can't remember which...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **debsums** to do this. From the man page:

> debsums is intended primarily as a way of  determining  what 
>   installed
>          files  have  been  locally  modified by the administrator...

You will need to install debsums yourself as it is not installed by default.

I found when I tested this that it complained about most packages not having md5 checksums so I ran

`sudo checksums_init`

This looks for packages that did not install their md5sums
       files. Then, it will generate those md5sums files from the binary packages downloaded via APT if available.

Once that was completed I ran :

`sudo debsums -ce > ~/changed-configs.txt`

and that produces a file called changed-configs.txt that lists configuration changes made locally compared to the files provided from the repositories.

I think that should provide what you need.

Comment: Off topic but just for reference in case anyone uses rpm distros, on rpm based systems you can do `rpm -Va` to find changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you edited them via the terminal, you could search your bash history. i.e.

```
grep 'smb.conf' ~/.bash_history
```

or

```
grep 'nano' ~/.bash_history
```

I've done this a few times on a server when I was trying to document what I had done previously. It would be a good idea to back up your bash_history first though.

Comment: Server old. Bash history long gone. Nice idea though.

Comment: I would just back up any configs you deem important to the running of the server. Most likely some things in the configs will be changed in newer versions anyway. What I like to do when I create a server is create a folder /var/server_backup, then create symlinks to all config files I change (keeping full paths from root starting at /var/server_backup), then I rsync this daily to a backup. Won't help here, but something to keep in mind moving forward.